# cant get image from server to android application

Tags: php, android

i am building application which have the ability to search users and get there information. the situation is that when i run it on the emulator everything is fine but when i run it on my real server sometimes i get the user detailed and sometimes not.
i don't know why i get some users and other not. i check and the users that was does not exist i get the failed message but for other users that exists i get the  message.

for example:
correct result:

```
  {"flag":"user found","users":[{"name":"nir","email":"nirb@g.com","mobile":"0543536434","image":"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
```

when it failed i get:

```
{"flag":"user not found"}
```

for other existing users:

```
 <html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://biz.nf/errors/403.html" /></head><body></body></html>
```

i do not have any idea why its happend:

i just found that if i take off those 2 lines

```
$img_path = "images/".$row["image"];

$imgdata = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_path));

and 
"image" => $imgdata
```

the result is fine. does my image decoding process correct? because in 1 user i get the image but in others not.

this is my java code:

```
  package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.ImageConvertor;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.InviteUsersArrayAdapter;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.InviteUsersListRow;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class InviteUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText editTextSearch;
    private Button btnSave,btnDiscard;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private List<InviteUsersListRow> rowUser;
    private DBcontroller dbController;
    public static final String EXTRA_USERS  = "";
    ListView listViewUsers;
    List<InviteUsersListRow> rowUsers;
    private InviteUsersArrayAdapter Useradapter = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invite_users);

        editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);
        btnDiscard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonDiscard);
        editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(editTextSearch.getText().length() > 0) {
                    Log.d("send request","searching...");
                    sendDataToDBController();
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("do nothing","doing nothing");
                   if(Useradapter != null) {
                       Log.d("do nothing","clear adapter");
                       /*Useradapter.clear();
                       Useradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                       listViewUsers.setAdapter(null);
                   }
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        btnDiscard.setOnClickListener(this);
        listViewUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewusers);
        listViewUsers.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(String resStr) {
        Log.d("invite_Response", resStr);
        if (resStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resStr);
                String flg = json.getString("flag");

                Log.d("flag",flg);
                switch (flg){

                    case "user found":{
                        JSONArray jsonarr = json.getJSONArray("users");
                        Log.d("array",jsonarr.toString());
                        rowUsers = new ArrayList<InviteUsersListRow>();
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length();i++){
                            {
                                Log.d("user is", jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                                String name = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                                String mobile = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("mobile");
                                Bitmap profileImage = ImageConvertor.decodeBase64(jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("image"));
                                int  imgStatus = R.drawable.add_user_50;
                                if(Useradapter != null){
                                    Log.d("Useradapter invited size:",String.valueOf(Useradapter.getUsers().size()));
                                    for(int j = 0 ;j<Useradapter.getUsers().size();j++)
                                    {
                                        if(Useradapter.getUsers().get(j).getDesc().equals(mobile))
                                        {
                                             imgStatus = R.drawable.remove_user_50;
                                            Log.d("set status2.1",String.valueOf(imgStatus));
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }else{

                                    imgStatus = R.drawable.add_user_50;
                                    Log.d("set status1",String.valueOf(imgStatus));
                                }
                                InviteUsersListRow rowUser = new InviteUsersListRow(imgStatus, name, mobile,profileImage);
                                rowUsers.add(rowUser);
                            }
                            if(Useradapter == null)
                                Useradapter = new InviteUsersArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.invite_users_listview_row,rowUsers);
                            else {
                                {
                                    Useradapter.setData(rowUsers);
                                    Useradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                            listViewUsers.setAdapter(Useradapter);

                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else
             Log.d("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToDBController() {

        String username = editTextSearch.getText().toString();
        BasicNameValuePair tagreq = new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "search_user");
        BasicNameValuePair name = new BasicNameValuePair("name", username);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(tagreq);
        nameValuePairList.add(name);
        dbController = new DBcontroller(this,this);
        dbController.execute(nameValuePairList);

    }





    @Override
    public void preProcess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.ButtonDiscard:
            {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,i);;
                finish();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.ButtonSave:
            {

                if(Useradapter != null )
                {
                    if(Useradapter.getUsers().size() > 0)
                    {
                        Log.d("adapter size:",String.valueOf(Useradapter.getUsers().size()));
                        Intent i = getIntent();


                        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
                        for(int j = 0 ;j < Useradapter.getUsers().size();j++)
                        {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                                jsonObj.put("name",Useradapter.getUsers().get(j).getTitle());
                                jsonObj.put("mobile",Useradapter.getUsers().get(j).getDesc());
                                jsonArr.put(jsonObj);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        Log.d("json users",jsonArr.toString());
                        i.putExtra("userList", jsonArr.toString());
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("adapter size <0", "search is empty");
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

this is the server side:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 9/24/2015
 * Time: 11:29 AM
 */
include 'response_process.php';
class SearchUser implements ResponseProcess{


    public function dataProcess($dblink)
    {
        $output = array();
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $output["flag"]="user found";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.name LIKE '$name%'";

        $result = mysqli_query($dblink,$query) or die (mysqli_error($dblink));

        if(!$result){
            $output["flag"] = "query failed";
            $output["query_msg"] = $result;

        }else{
            $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($no_of_rows < 1)
                $output["flag"]="user not found";   //user not found
            else{
                $output["flag"]="user found";
                $output["users"] = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $img_path = "images/".$row["image"];

                    $imgdata = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_path));
                    $output["users"][] =  array("name"=> $row["name"],"email"=> $row["email"],"mobile" => $row["mobile"],"image" => $imgdata);
                }


            }



        }

        echo json_encode($output);

    }
}
```

Comment: Check whether the username is correct (check uppercase, lowercase..)

Comment: i already check that everything is correct.

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly on MySQL with the failed usernames?

Comment: example when i click "nir" i get "nir"  user and "Nir" user but when i click "matan" i get the "<html> message while this user is existing.

Comment: Could you check whether there's any php error log in your PHP server?

Comment: i didn't found the error log. my server is host by the website http://cp1.biz.nf/

Comment: does the image size should made any effect because the image that i succeeded to get was 7.5 KB and all the rest above 30 KB

Comment: Check the Log files in the server,also from the server Check whether you are sending the link to the image or you are pushing the actual bytes to the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem.
for some reason the size of the image was effect on the transferred so i re size the bitmap by 50%.

now everything is working.

Comment: it's good you found the problem. However, I noticed that you are parsing JSON all by yourself. There are many libraries in android which will reduce the above code to 15 lines and prevent you from some very nasty and hard to find bugs. Try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it is worth it.

Comment: you should try GSON or Jackson ;)